How to perform functionality in the Flutter app even if the app is closed?
I make a step counter app in this app when my app is open or open in background it works perfectly but when I close my app the step counting is not working it stops.
I have try to perform this using another package flutter_background_executor but this package also not working when app is closed.
Please help me to solve this, Thank You.

https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
